# how to stop onclick event on list for 1.5 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with 4 choices, and after i click on certain choice there is an animation that goes for about 1.5 seconds so in that period of time I want to be able to make the other links in the menu not clickable( but without using .on of off methods) and after the 1.5 seconds to make the all links in the menu clickable again

```
  $("#Link3").click(function(){ 



$('#LinkDiv31').fadeOut(300);
$('#ImageBingingDiv').fadeOut(300);
$("#Link1").off("click");
$("#Link2").off("click");
$("#Link4").off("click");





}
```

Comment: Use some flag. If flag is enabled - click works, otherwise not

Comment: And why not with on / off, that's what they are there for ?

Comment: Just use an external function ?

Comment: $("#Link2").delay(1200).on("click",function(){ExternalLinkDiv2();});
 the delay doesn't delay as it should....the event is right away ready

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Link2").on('click', link2);
$("#Link3").on('click', link3);

function link2() {
    // do stuff for #Link2
}

function link3() {
    $('#LinkDiv31').fadeOut(300);
    $('#ImageBingingDiv').fadeOut(300);
    $("#Link1, #Link2, #Link4").off("click");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#Link1").on("click", link1);
        $("#Link2").on("click", link2);
        $("#Link4").on("click", link4);
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: now i have issue i have toggle inside the link2 function and toggles 2-3 times....i've put alerts inside and it calls the function 4-5 times...

Comment: Then it's bound with on() more times then it's unbound with off(), making it fire multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickEnabled = true;
$( "#Link2" ).on( 'click' , clickFunc );

function clickFunc() {
    if ( clickEnabled ) {
        clickEnabled = false;
        // do your code
        setTimeout( function() { clickEnabled = true } , 1000 ); 
        // or you can use callback in fadeOut
        $( '#someDiv' ).fadeOut( 300 , function() { clickEnabled = true } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that you are trying to solve:

1) Executing some event after the animation is complete: You can achieve this using queue and dequeue methods provided by jQuery.

2) Disabling links: You can achieve this using modal overlays.

Refer to the example I have created at jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kamatanay/qyDDB/1/

It makes use of [easyModal](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/easyModal.js) library.

HTML:

```
<a id="Link1" href="#">Link1</a>
<a id="Link2" href="#">Link2</a>
<a id="Link3" href="#">Link3</a>
<a id="Link4" href="#">Link4</a>

<div class="modal"></div>


<div id="LinkDiv31">This is LinkDiv31</div>
<div id="ImageBingingDiv">This is ImageBingingDiv</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".modal").easyModal({
        overlayOpacity: 0.0,
        overlayColor: "#FFFF",    
        overlayClose: false,
        closeOnEscape: false
});  


$("#Link3").click(function(){ 

    $(".modal").trigger('openModal');  

    $('#LinkDiv31').fadeOut(300);
    $('#ImageBingingDiv').fadeOut(300);

    $("#ImageBingingDiv").queue(function(){
        $(".modal").trigger('closeModal');
        $("#ImageBingingDiv").dequeue();        
    });    

});
```

I hope that helps in solving your problem.